# Maya Python: GridLayout - Different width per Cell

Tags: python, layout, maya, grid-layout

So i am trying to figure out how to have a gridlayout in maya, where 2 cells in the same row vary in width.

i tried indexing the cells in the cellWidth flag, but with no success.
this is what i have so far:

```
cmds.gridLayout( numberOfColumns=2, cellWidthHeight=(50, 40) )
```

and something like this is what i want:

```
cmds.gridLayout( numberOfColumns=2, cellWidthHeight=([1]=50, 40), [2]=100, 40) )
```

anyone got an idea?

regards
Dave

Comment: I looked at [rowColumnLayout](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2009help/CommandsPython/rowColumnLayout.html) which says you can do something like `cmds.rowColumnLayout( numberOfColumns=2, columnWidth=[(1, 50), (2, 100)] )`, different size widths but it seems you also want different heights?

Comment: thanks. you are right, the rowColumLayout does have a rowHight flag, though it always tells me :Row height meaningless for vertically oriented layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]

Wow, i am so silly. 
The more than easy solution is to simply adjust the `height` and `width` of each control within a `Layout` individually, since you can just set the `height` and `width` of a button or `intField` etc.